# Edit newsletter

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a newsletter creation with the possibility to add new modules and modify them directly online. In this example I took the case of my links that I can modify by displaying a modal with a field to enter the URL of the link and a field for the link title. But this example is valid for editing other content like: image, text, ... etc.

Each newsletter has an id that I attach to its content. I want to make that upgrade. The problem is that I will add other modules to the newsletter to personalize it. These new modules will also be modifiable.

My concern is I can not save my changes. Thank you for your help.

Javascript:

```
console.clear();
(function hover_edit() {
    var big_parent;
    $(".row-edit").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).append('<span class="row-edit-hover"><i class="fa fa-pencil" style="line-height:30px;"></i></span>');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children(".row-edit-hover").remove();
        }
    )
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    });
    $("body").on('click', ".row-edit-hover i", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        big_parent = $(this).parents('.row-edit');
        //edit link
        if (big_parent.data("type") == 'link') {
            $("#edit-link .title").val(big_parent.text());
            $("#edit-link .url").val(big_parent.attr("href"));
            $("#edit-link").fadeIn(500);
            $("#edit-link .edit-box").slideDown(500);
        }
    });
    $("#edit-link .edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
        var toSave = {};
        $(this).parents('.edit').fadeOut(500)
            .children().slideUp(500);
        big_parent.text($("#edit-link .title").val());
        big_parent.attr("href", $("#edit-link .url").val());
        toSave = {
            'id': big_parent.data('id'),
            'url': big_parent.attr('href'),
            'text': big_parent.text()
        }
        console.info(toSave);
        $.post("page-update_base.php", toSave, function(response) {
            if (response.status) {
                $("#msg").removeClass('danger');
                $("#msg").addClass('success').html(response.msg);
            } else {
                $("#msg").removeClass('success');
                $("#msg").addClass('danger').html(response.msg);
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
    $("#edit-link .edit-box-buttons-cancel").click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.edit').fadeOut(500)
            .children().slideUp(500);
    });
})();
```

PHP:

```
<? 
    // page-update_base.php
    // include connection file
    include_once("db.php");
    //récupération "propre" des variable)
    $id   = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : "";
    $url  = isset($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : "";
    $text = isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : "";

    if ($id == 1) {
        //préparation de la requete et des variables
        $sql   = "UPDATE tbl_newsletter SET url_1 = :url, titre_url_1 = :text WHERE newsletter_id = :id";
        $datas = array(
            ":url" => $url,
            ":text" => $text,
            ":id" => $id
        );
        //exécution de la requete
        try {
            $req = $db->prepare($sql);
            $req->execute($datas);
            $msg = array(
                'status' => true,
                'msg' => 'Saisie enregistr&eacute;e avec success !',
                'debug' => ""
            );
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            //erreur dans la requete
            $msg = array(
                'status' => false,
                'msg' => 'Erreur ! ' . $e->getMessage(),
                'debug' => array(
                    "requete" => $sql,
                    "datas" => $datas
                )
            );
        }
    } else if ($id == 2) {
        //préparation de la requete et des variables
        $sql   = "UPDATE tbl_newsletter SET url_2 = :url, titre_url_2 = :text WHERE newsletter_id = :id";
        $datas = array(
            ":url" => $url,
            ":text" => $text,
            ":id" => $id
        );
        //exécution de la requete
        try {
            $req = $db->prepare($sql);
            $req->execute($datas);
            $msg = array(
                'status' => true,
                'msg' => 'Saisie enregistr&eacute;e avec success !',
                'debug' => ""
            );
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            //erreur dans la requete
            $msg = array(
                'status' => false,
                'msg' => 'Erreur ! ' . $e->getMessage(),
                'debug' => array(
                    "requete" => $sql,
                    "datas" => $datas
                )
            );
        }
    } else if ($id == 3) {
        //préparation de la requete et des variables
        $sql   = "UPDATE tbl_newsletter SET url_3 = :url, titre_url_3 = :text WHERE newsletter_id = :id";
        $datas = array(
            ":url" => $url,
            ":text" => $text,
            ":id" => $id
        );
        //exécution de la requete
        try {
            $req = $db->prepare($sql);
            $req->execute($datas);
            $msg = array(
                'status' => true,
                'msg' => 'Saisie enregistr&eacute;e avec success !',
                'debug' => ""
            );
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            //erreur dans la requete
            $msg = array(
                'status' => false,
                'msg' => 'Erreur ! ' . $e->getMessage(),
                'debug' => array(
                    "requete" => $sql,
                    "datas" => $datas
                )
            );
        }
    } else {
        //pas d'ID
        $msg = array(
            'status' => false,
            'msg' => "Erreur ! ID de ligne vide !",
            'debug' => $_POST
        );
    }
    // send data as json format
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h4>Item 1</h4>
    <p>Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae  nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus:  eosque ut heiulans baiolorum praecentor ad expediendum quod orsi sunt  incitans vocibus crebris. qui haut longe postea ideo vivus exustus est.</p>
    <div ><a href="http://link-j-en-profite" class="row-edit" data-type="link" data-id="<?=$row1['newsletter_id'];?>">J'en profite</a></div>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Item 2</h4>
    <p>Incenderat autem audaces usque ad insaniam homines ad haec, quae  nefariis egere conatibus, Luscus quidam curator urbis subito visus:  eosque ut heiulans baiolorum praecentor ad expediendum quod orsi sunt  incitans vocibus crebris. qui haut longe postea ideo vivus exustus est.</p>
    <div ><a href="http://link-contact" class="row-edit" data-type="link" data-id="<?=$row1['newsletter_id'];?>">Contact</a></div>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Item 3</h4>
    <p>Splendida porro oculi fugitant vitantque tueri. sol etiam caecat, contra si tendere pergas,propterea quia vis magnast.</p>
    <div ><a href="http://link-a-propos" class="row-edit" data-type="link" data-id="<?=$row1['newsletter_id'];?>">A propos</a></div>
</div>
<!-- Modale -->
<div class="edit" id="edit-link">
    <div class="edit-box" style="">
        <div class="edit-box-title">Edit Link</div>
        <div class="edit-box-content">
            <div class="edit-box-content-text">Title</div>
            <div class="edit-box-content-field"><input type="text" class="edit-box-content-field-input title"/></div>
            <div class="edit-box-content-text">URL:<span>(full address including   http://)</span></div>
            <div class="edit-box-content-field"><input type="text" class="edit-box-content-field-input url"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="edit-box-buttons">
            <div class="edit-box-buttons-save">Save</div>
            <div class="edit-box-buttons-cancel">Cancel</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may have a concern, yet it's hard to understand what you expect the community what answer to provide. This question most likely will be closed. Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have an extra curly bracket in your PHP